# ClassNotFoundException When Deserializing List of Objects in Scala

Tags: scala, serialization

I have a List of objects that I am able to serialize to disk.  When I attempt to read them back in, a ClassNotFoundException is thrown.  Why is this?

Here is my list of objects that I need to serialize.  Notice these are case classes and so they are serializable.

```
scala> case class Foo(x: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> val foos = List(new Foo(2), new Foo(3))
foos: List[Foo] = List(Foo(2), Foo(3))
```

Some simple housekeeping to setup the output file on disk.

```
scala> val path = "/tmp/foos.ser"
path: String = /tmp/foos.ser

scala> import java.io._
import java.io._

scala> val file = new File(path)
file: java.io.File = /tmp/foos.ser
```

Now serialize the List of objects to disk.

```
scala> val out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))
out: java.io.ObjectOutputStream = java.io.ObjectOutputStream@22db002d

scala> out.writeObject(foos)

scala> out.close
```

When I attempt to deserialize the List objects I get a ClassNotFoundException.  Why can it not found the class Foo?

```
scala> val in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))
in: java.io.ObjectInputStream = java.io.ObjectInputStream@27cf2513

scala> val events = in.readObject().asInstanceOf[List[Foo]]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Foo
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  ...
```

Comment: Have you tried making the class implement the `Serializable` trait?

Comment: This example you provided is working as expected without errors for me. Do you restart the REPL in between serializing and deserializing the list? If you do, then you need to re-declare `case class Foo(x: Int)` again.

Comment: This is really weird.  It was not working on my Ubuntu Linux machine at work, but on my Mac it does work.  I'll have to dig into this more.  Thanks for verifying that it works for you.

Comment: It works fine if I open a fresh REPL, but its not working it I open a REPL in a project that I am working on using 'sbt console'.  There must be something in the project that makes this not work.  Hmm.

Comment: The true (i.e. full) name of a class defined in the REPL depends on the line you have it defined in. Therefore, if you have two REPL sessions where `Foo` does not appear on the same line, the JVM will not find your class (since they do not have the same name). I'd advise against using the REPL to define classes for serialization testing.